# How to open a file in binary format.(1's & 0's)

Tags: binary-files

I want to open files in binary format. I want to see binary code, not hex. And want to edit in binary format and ability to save changes. What is the best application to do this or is there any easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

Download: http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Downloads/free-hex-editor

[image]

Open a file and choose the binary edit dialog.

[image]

This will let you edit\view one byte at a time.

Another way is using [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753271/how-to-convert-char-to-its-ascii-binary-code) or practically any other programming language you like. As you can see it isn't much code.

Comment: I agree with this. Find something that deals with mostly Hex, binary for the few places where it makes a difference. You only want to deal with a few binary bytes, not a whole file.